# RESTful client communicating with Freeradius server

Tags: java, freeradius

I have successfully installed the Freeradius server on Ubuntu 14.04. It is up and running perfectly with local client(from the source code downloaded from freeradius site). Now my next task is to have the Freeradius server communicate with a Restful client. I did a thorough search on this topic but did not find any answers on how to go about. I would like to implement a RESTful client in java and communicate with FreeRadius server for authentication and authorization. If there are any good tutorials on how to do this, Please provide me the useful links or sample codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try a look to http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/ or just search google for *java radius*, you will find multiple libraries to connect to radius.

Start out just writing a small prototype application in standalone java, just to test the functionalities you need, once you have achieved this it will be time to code this in a webcontainer (Tomcat, Wildfly, Jetty, Glassfish ...) to program the RESTful API.

Be aware this question is not suitable for serverfault, as questions must be on a current trouble you have, exposing what you have test so far. Questions asking for advice of what products to use generally are not well received.